# Comparing two json lists which are converted into objects using an assertion

Tags: java, linux, json

I am connecting to two websites, taking the json from each site, and converting them into  java objects. Now these objects are lists and I want to compare the two to see if if everything in list one is the same as everything in list two. I have tried the following but I get the error under the assertThat that  I need to create a new method that contains assertThat, but I am just simply writing a junit test?

`

```
@Test
   public void test_1() throws Exception 
{

        List<Sample> proj1 = getProject1();
        List<Sample> proj2 = getProject2();
        assertThat(proj1, hasItem(proj2));
   }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's because your hasItem(proj2) is actually passing a full list, not a single item to evaluate.

For example, if you change it to:

```
assertThat(proj1, hasItem(proj2.get(0)));
```

It should be a valid method call

If you want to compare a list of items then this may help: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/matchers/JUnitMatchers.html

Comment: I already have 
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

Comment: that's good, sound like you're including the libraries correctly then...maybe it's the arguments that are being passed to assertThat causing the problem then.